# How to set navigation drawer right margin?

Tags: android, layout, navigation-drawer

As per title, how can I set the right margin of the navigation drawer to 56 dp as per Google's material design (refer below)? I have tried `android:layout_marginRight="56dp"` in the second view of the `DrawerLayout` but it looks very weird (more than 56dp and very different from google's material design picture below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that you focus on the width of the Second `View` of `DeawerLayout` which should be within [240dp to 320dp](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html),

Think about this you manage to give `navigation drawer` right margin of 56 dp on the right side, now you want to check this in `landscape` mode, and more surprises will be waiting for you

Comment: haha I think you are right. It will look very weird in landscape mode if it has a right margin of 56dp. Then what is the point of specifying 56dp in the Google's material design guidelines? Does that mean I should not follow the guidelines?

Comment: @Sevin, they may be trying to say no one is perfect, or have two different margins for landscape and portrait mode which I don't think would be suitable

Answer (score 0):

#### Try focus on the width of the navigation drawer, it should be in between **240dp** to **320dp**. It will automatically adjust with the right margin.

---

This is an example of the xml file  which contains the navigation drawer fragment. Here the width of the fragment is set in the dimens folder as 280dp

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                layout="@layout/app_bar" />

            <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
                android:id="@+id/materialTabHost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
                app:accentColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:hasIcons="true"
                app:iconColor="@android:color/white"
                app:primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/materialTabHost"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.fragments.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

### Now this is an example which is the layout of the navigation drawer

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="com.example.fragments.FragmentDrawer">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## It will be a good practice if you set the width in the dimens folder rather than hardcoding it.